# Are blood pressure numbers recorded during an office visit really meaningful?

Tags: test, hypertension, healthcare-data

On a recent visit to my primary care doctor the staff did the perfunctory BP reading. I had just sat down a few seconds prior. The reading was done only once.

Is such a reading at all meaningful?

I found [this article](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2006/04/060420232237.htm) which seems to suggest that the common practice of measuring too quickly skews the numbers:

> “Currently, most patients get called back for their appointment, sit on the table, and immediately get their blood pressure measured,” Turner said. “Our study reaffirmed the American Heart Association’s technique that patients should sit in a calm environment with feet flat on the floor, resting their back against the chair for at least five minutes before taking a blood pressure measurement on a bare arm at heart level. All too often, this doesn’t happen. ”

Isn't this a form of malpractice?

Comment: Where's the prior research?

Comment: If by, "...just sat down" you mean you just walked across the parking lot and up a flight of stairs (well, maybe not necessarily the last), then no, whatever BP the nurse/assistant measured was most definitely not your resting BP. You might try Googling, "How to measure resting blood pressure."

Comment: I don't think so ; it is always substantially higher for me than when I take it at home.

Comment: I've decided that I'm not going to let them enter the numbers into the system anymore unless they do it right.

Comment: @Ruminator That comment makes me think you do understand what they did wrong, which means you have done some sort of prior research. I hate to keep closing your questions, so would you please just follow the site requirements?

Comment: Please quote the most important part of your article and include a tiny bit more (perhaps sth like http://www.bloodpressureuk.org/BloodPressureandyou/Medicaltests/Whitecoateffect )?